# Android paytm like wallet implementation

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay

I want to implement a custom wallet in my android app. But I cant differentiate which mechanism follow to implement the wallet. Can anybody help me the detail process to implement the custom wallet. Also what need to follow Google wallet integration or In App purchasing.

The paytm wallet is the best example which I want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own wallet or use any existing wallet as payment method. Creating a wallet in Java with 5-6 developer for 2-3 years will help you to come-up with a fairly competitive product if the goal, design, and process are clearly defined.

If you are looking for existing vendors you can use Paytm wallet which offers SDK for Android / iOs along with multiple other server side mobile utilities. you can explore them on [PaywithPaytm](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/#Mobile_SKDs) website.